# JFrame Dimension issue

Tags: java, static-methods

```
public class bioscope extends Component{

static int width;
static int height;

public void paint(Graphics g){
    try {
        BufferedImage crow = ImageIO.read(new File("photos/houseCrow.jpg"));
        this.width = crow.getWidth();
        this.height = crow.getHeight();
        System.out.println(this.height);    
        System.out.println(this.width); 
        g.drawImage(crow, 0, 0, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bioscope: Have a peek!");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new bioscope());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(bioscope.width, bioscope.height);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //frame.setResizable(false);
    System.out.println(bioscope.height);
    System.out.println(bioscope.width); 
}
}
```

Output window has zero height and width, which is frustrating but still seems explicable. What stuns me is the output of println commands. I expected this to be a four line output: 492,640,492,640. But it prints out 0,0 first, and apparently halts. But go fullscreen, and 492,640 will be appended at the printout! Now you-know-who would invoke println every time you go fullscreen, and another 492,640 would be appended. Sort of similar appendings will occur if you minimize or try to resize JFrame window.

Why this would happen, and why JFrame window wasn't of dimensions 492,640 at the first place? The image was attached successfully, though, as could be seen if I resized the window.

Comment: Why do you expect `492,640,492,640`? Where are these values?

Comment: 492,640 are, of course, the height and width of the image I am adding to my JFrame window. Sorry because my question appeared incomplete a while ago, I did complete the post but couldn't imagine the draft would be saved only partially for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you expect your two static fields *width* and *height* to have any effect on the actual dimensions of the component, or if you're just using them for debugging. The static fields you have declared shadow the `width` and `height` fields in `Component`. It would be more appropriate to use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` to track the actual values used by the super class.

It prints `0, 0` first because the static fields are not initialized until the first paint. The `paint` method is only called when the frame is redrawn, which is why you see the log line every time you change the size of the window.

Try this:

```
public class bioscope extends JComponent {
    transient BufferedImage crow;

    public bioscope() {
        try {
            crow = ImageIO.read(new File("photos/houseCrow.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(crow.getWidth(), crow.getHeight()));
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(crow, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bioscope: Have a peek!");
        bioscope bioscope = new bioscope();
        frame.getContentPane().add(bioscope);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```